# How to add fadeout/in effect in iframe with links rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have create the following html page with an iframe which rotate 3 links how can i add fade out and in effect when rotate the links?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="foo" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
        <script>
            (function() {
                var e = document.getElementById('foo'),
                    f = function( el, url ) {
                        el.src = url;
                    },
                    urls = [
                    'http://link1',
                    'http://link2'
                    ],
                    i = 0,
                    l = urls.length;

                    (function rotation() {
                        if ( i != l-1 ) { 
                            i++
                        } else {
                            i = 0;
                        }
                        f( e, urls[i] );
                        setTimeout( arguments.callee, 5000 );
                    })();
            })();
        </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the jquery FadeOut and FadeIn function.
http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

In the tags it says you are using jquery, however the majority of your code doesn't look quite jquery-like.

In your rotation function you could add something like:

```
$('a#linkID').fadeOut(300)
```

Or to make it a bit more general, you can pass the element to the rotation function and act on that.

```
   function rotation(eleID) {
   $(eleID).fadeOut(300)
   if ( i != l-1 ) { 
     i++
    } else {
    i = 0;
    }
    f( e, urls[i] );
    setTimeout( arguments.callee, 5000 );
    }
```

I hope this helps!